# Array index out of bounds in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sqlite

I am trying to create an app that takes values from a database created using SQLite and plotted using AndroidPlot. The portion that is creating trouble in the MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);

    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> voltages = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();

    Number[] seriesNumbers = {};
    for(i = 0; i < voltages.size(); i++){
        seriesNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(voltages.get(i));
    }
}
```

There is no error while building the code. However, when run on the emulator, it states "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0". 
The database has one column, named 'voltages' with 10 entries. The DatabaseAccess.java code is as given below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

/**
 * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context the Context
 * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a List of quotes
 */
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from voltages", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: your array has no size: Number[] seriesNumbers = {}; so it will crash if you try to put something at index 0.

Comment: use an `ArrayList<Number>` instead of a regular array. Arrays in Java are not dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the declaration of `Number[] seriesNumbers = {};`

You must give it a size.

```
Number[] seriesNumbers = new Number[voltages.size()];
```

Comment: Should have realized that. Works like a charm! Thanks.